# How to condense multiple IF statements simply in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, statements

Here if my code. It works and runs and does everything I want it to do, but its too long. How can I condense it? My PHP level is basic.

Would I use an array? or a function? Can you kindly post the code you would use to make this more efficient?

```
<?php
$product = $result[CategoryId];

if ($product == "1") {
    echo "Tonneau Cover to suit";
} elseif ($product == "2") {
    echo "Clip On Tonneau Cover to suit";
} elseif ($product == "3") {
    echo "INSERT";
} elseif ($product == "4") {
    echo "INSERT";
} elseif ($product == "5") {
    echo "INSERT";
} elseif ($product == "6") {
    echo "INSERT";
} elseif ($product == "7") {
    echo "INSERT";
} elseif ($product == "8") {
    echo "INSERT";
} elseif ($product == "9") {
    echo "INSERT";
} elseif ($product == "10") {
    echo "INSERT";
} elseif ($product == "11") {
    echo "INSERT";
} elseif ($product == "12") {
    echo "INSERT";
} elseif ($product == "13") {
    echo "INSERT";
} elseif ($product == "14") {
    echo "INSERT";
} elseif ($product == "15") {
    echo "INSERT";
} elseif ($product == "16") {
    echo "INSERT";
} elseif ($product == "17") {
    echo "INSERT";
} else {
    echo ".";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can use array in this manner

```
$product = $result[CategoryId];
$ogh=["Tonneau Cover to suit","Clip On Tonneau Cover to suit","INSERT"];
if(count($ogh)>$product)
  echo $ogh[$product];
else
    echo "Invalid";
```

Comment: but how does it use the CategoryId (which is a result pulled from a MySQL database)

Comment: to show you an  example i had set product value as 3 check i have updated my answer and replace '3' by  $result[CategoryId];

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have in the example:

```
<?php
$product = (int) $result['CategoryId'];

if ($product === 1) {
    echo "Tonneau Cover to suit";
} elseif ($product === 2) {
    echo "Clip On Tonneau Cover to suit";
} elseif ($product >=3 || $product <=17) {
    echo "INSERT";
} else {
    echo ".";
}
?>
```

Comment: No the values 3 to 17 willeach have different "echo" statements. I just put insert in there to save time rather then typing each thing out.

Comment: Then you should either use an array, or probably put them in your database, to relate to whatever data they should go with.

Comment: What would that Array look like?

Comment: probably a numeric indexed array starting at 1.